# How to change the color of a link without using ID preference?

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm facing is, I couldn't change the color of the unvisited link without using the ID preference. Am I missing some core knowledge? What is the difference between;

```
a:link {
    background-color: red;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and

```
#change {
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

The first code part changes the background color but the color of the font remains unchanged. To change the color of the font I needed to used the second code part the one with `'change'` as ID.

Sample code as follows: https://codepen.io/can-zgen/pen/GbVyLv

(The part that I'm talking about is at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Also, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Totally forgot that IDs must be unique. Changed it to class.

Comment: the snippet that you provided is working fine with a:link{color: aliceblue;}

Comment: It is not working for me: https://imgur.com/a/Pse6W8q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the CSS selectors you want are `a:link`([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp)) to style unvisited links and `a:visited`([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)) to style visited links.

On a side note, I think your code is working but you have "visited" the links before So, `a:link` is not applied for you; `a:visited` is applied. Try doing you dev work for this using Incognito in Chrome (or the equivalent mode in your browser of choice)

Comment: No problem! Sometimes the easiest problems are the hardest to solve. Glad I could  help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` as a class. After that you should use javascript to add this class once the link is clicked for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

a:link color is not working probably because its overwritten by some other css. You can try -

```
a {
    background-color: red;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or

```
a, a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: red;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and it will work. And if you want to make it specific to only netflix and youtube (from your example), then you can do as follows -

```
.lilBox a {
        background-color: red;
        color: aliceblue;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```